# What is the best way to query these tables? Inner Join?

Tags: mysql

**database**: showsdb

**tables**:

- shows  (id, date, venue, city, state, length, source, source2, rating)
- songs (id, name)
- shows_songs (shows_id, songs_id)

I want to be able to query the shows table and display all the songs from that show.  I also want to query the songs table and display all the shows where that song appears.

For example:

shows table has 2 shows.  3 songs played at each show.

songs table has 5 songs.  Some of those songs were played at show1.  some at show2.  some at both

**show1** setlist: song1, song2, song3

**show2** setlist: song2,song4, song5

Do I need a FK in one of these tables?  How would that look?  Or can this be done with joins?  I am not too clear on that either.

Thanks for your help and suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would show all shows, that run that ne song.

```
SELECT
    s1.date
    , s1.venue, s1.city, s1.state, s1.length, s1.source, s1.source2, s1.rating,
    s3.name
FROM 
        shows s1
    INNER JOIN 
        shows_songs s2
        ON s2.shows_id = s1.id
    INNER JOIN 
        songs  s3
        ON s2.songs_id = s3.id
WHERE s3.name = "Walk like an Egyptian"
```

`Foreign keys` are needed when you want to guarantee, that in the *shows_songs*  are only shows/songs that already exist, but usually that you will do at app level, but with a foreign key restrainto you can't enter false data.

another Option is a FOREIGN KEY with `ON DELETE CASCADE` for example between *shows* and *shows_songs*, this would delete an entry from *shows_songs* when the shows would be deleted.

But in your case you don't need a foreign key.

An `INNER JOIN` is then need when you need to retrieve data from different shows.name and songs.name, then you need always to join the bridge table before the second table.

And take a good look at [Aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)

Because

```
SELECT
    s1.venue,s3.name
FROM 
        shows s1
    INNER JOIN 
        shows_songs s2
        ON s2.shows_id = s1.id
    INNER JOIN 
        songs  s3
        ON s2.songs_id = s3.id
WHERE s1.id = 1
```

Would result in

```
venue    name
venue1   song1
venue1   song2
venue1   song3
venue1   song4
```

Which could be made to a single row with `GROUP_CONCAT`

this is a small database, so you can test the queries and results quite fast